# Visualizing the e_g and t_2g orbitals in case of tetrahedral crystal field splitting

Tags: coordination-compounds, crystal-field-theory

I am reading about the crystal field theory (CFT) for the case of tetrahedral coordination entities. I understand that the $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ orbital is nearer to the ligand than the $\mathrm{e_g}$ orbital, from the data of the angles between the respective orbitals, central metal atom and the ligands. But I do have the following questions:

1. Deriving the angle for the $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ and $\mathrm{e_g}$ orbital mathematically.

   The angle in case of $\mathrm{e_g}$ orbital is roughly $55^\circ,$ which seems to come from dividing the tetrahedral angle by $2.$ Also, the angle in case of $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ orbital comes out as $35^{\circ}16',$ which I have no idea about.
2. Positional analysis.

   Lee's *Concise inorganic chemistry* [1, p. 220] states that

   > Alternatively the $\mathrm{t_{2g}}$ orbitals are half the side of the cube away from the approach of the ligands, whilst the $\mathrm{e_g}$ orbitals are half of the diagonal of the cube away.

I believe the angles mentioned can be derived from the statement, but I'm not sure how the statement came about. It would be great if anyone could share some visual models of this part of CFT for tethrahedral coordination entities and suggest the right approach to understanding this.

#### Reference

1. Lee, J. D. *Concise Inorganic Chemistry*, 4th ed.; Chapman & Hall: London ; New York, **1991**. ISBN 978-0-412-40290-6.

Comment: I have some trouble understanding your question. Apparently you think orbitals can be reduced to a point ?

Comment: @Maurice I understand that orbitals cannot be reduced to a point, but for the angles we just need the directions which the lobes are pointing in alongwith the direction of approach of the ligands. I think that does clarify things up a bit. But still there's some confusion about the statement from my textbook quoted in the OP.

Comment: Due reasons of symmetry, there are $\textrm{t}_{\textrm{2g}}$ and $\textrm{e}_{\textrm{g}}$ sets of d orbitals in octahedral complexes. However, in tetrahedral complexes, these sets are reversed in energy, obviously, and now called $\textrm{t}_{\textrm{2}}$ and $\textrm{e}$, note the missing g.

Comment: draw a cube so that the x,y,z axes mark the centers of the faces. Place the 5 d orbital on the axes and diagonals as they are normally aligned. The four ligands in a tetrahedron are in corners of the cube, positioned so that they (obviously) form a tetrahedron. Then use the geometry to find the angles easily.

Comment: As you may want to calculate angles the d orbital functions in cartesians ( and without normalisation constants) are $Y^0_0=(3z^2-r^2)/r^2,\; Y^2_{-2}=(x-iy)^2/r^2,\;Y^2_{-1}=z(x-iy)/r^2,\;Y^2_2=(x+iy)^2/r^2,\;Y^2_1=-z(x+iy)/r^2$ where $ r^2$ is the distance to any point.